# RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for GoogLeNet: size mismatch

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

Currently I am trying to load my pretrained GoogleNet. However, there seems to be a size mismatch problem, I tried changed the num_classes to solve it, but to no avail, there is still problem.

```
import os
from tkinter import Variable
from matplotlib import image, transforms
import torch
import torchvision
from torch import nn, optim

checkpoint = torch.load("extraFile/Kaggle_googlenet.pth")
model = torchvision.models.googlenet(pretrained=True, num_classes = 3)

model.load_state_dict(checkpoint)
model.eval()

def predict_image(image_path):
    transformation = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224),
        transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
        ])
    image_tensor = transformation(image).float()
    image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        image_tensor.cuda()

    input = Variable(image_tensor)
    output = model(input)

    index = output.data.numpy().argmax()
    return index

if __name__ == "main":
    imagefile = "a.png"
    imagepath = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),imagefile)
    prediction = predict_image(imagepath)
    print("Predicted Class: ",prediction)
```

The error are

```
  File "c:\Users\soong\Documents\FYP\Fuzzy-Integral-Covid-Detection-main\extra.py", line 9, in <module>
    model = torchvision.models.googlenet(pretrained=True, num_classes = 3)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torchvision\models\googlenet.py", line 52, in googlenet
    model.load_state_dict(state_dict)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1051, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for GoogLeNet:
        size mismatch for aux1.fc2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3, 1024]).
        size mismatch for aux1.fc2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3]).
        size mismatch for aux2.fc2.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3, 1024]).
        size mismatch for aux2.fc2.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3]).
        size mismatch for fc.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000, 1024]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3, 1024]).
        size mismatch for fc.bias: copying a param with shape torch.Size([1000]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([3]).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `pretrained=True` option it will load a model which was trained on ImageNet and thus on 1000 classes.

What you do is that you load it and then reinitialized all layers which depend on the class size.

[Here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/finetuning_torchvision_models_tutorial.html) is a tutorial where it is done for different architectures, sadly not for GoogleNet. But the error should already show you which layers you have to initialize again with a lower class num. So i would start with the layers called `aux1.fc2`, `aux2.fc2`, `fc`.

Best way to start would be to do print the architecture first and have a look at the model. Looking for layers at the end which include 1000 in some form, which is a strong indicator it uses the class size.

```py
googlenet = torchvision.models.googlenet(pretrained=True)
print(googlenet)
```

From what I see, only the fully connected (`fc`) layer seems to actually exists the `aux1` and `aux2` are `None` for me, so this could already do

```py
googlenet = torchvision.models.googlenet(pretrained=True)
googlenet.fc = torch.nn.Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=3, bias=True)
```

Keep in mind that in order to use this you need a fine tuning on your defined classes on some dataset.

If you just want to run the classification on some data and want classes included in ImageNet you don't have to do anything special, just load the model without the `num_classes` and run it and map the ImageNet classes to the ones you need.